# hashCode method called for System.out.println() method in HashSet

Tags: java, hashcode

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

   class Employee {
    @Override
      public int hashCode() {
    System.out.println("Hash");
    return super.hashCode();
    }

}

 public class Test2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<Employee>set= new HashSet<>();
    Employee employee = new Employee();
    set.add(employee);
    System.out.println(set);// if we comment this "Hash" will be printed once
}
 }
```

Above code calls hashCode method 2 times if we print set. Why hashcode method is called on System.out.println()?

Comment: The hashCode Method is called when the object is inserted into the HashSet and when the Set is printed to the console. The hashCode is part of the default representation, if an object is printed to the console.

Comment: He knew that. He would like to know why.

Comment: I can understand it is called when inserted.But why it is called on Print statement?

Comment: This is because of `Object`'s `.toString()` implementation, which you call here

Comment: possible duplicate of [When HashSet call equal method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21626823/when-hashset-call-equal-method)

Comment: Please see my comment-edit above. Override the toString() method of Employee with a custom String returned to see the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29). In short, the default toString() function calls hashCode() and uses a hexadecimal representation of the hash as part of the String.

Comment: Which if you trace back, follows a similar logic to Object. Note the append call: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/StringBuilder.java#StringBuilder.append%28java.lang.Object%29 which calls valueOf http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.valueOf%28java.lang.Object%29 which calls the linked toString
EDIT: Deleted comment linked to http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#AbstractCollection.toString%28%29

Answer (score 3):

Find the following reason for printing `Hash` two times

1. For finding the hash value when you insert the `Employee` into the `HashSet`
2. When you print the set, it's calls the `hashCode()` method inside the default [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) method from `Object` class.

The default `toString()` method from `Object` class API docs says

> The `toString()` method for class Object returns a string consisting of
>   the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign
>   character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash
>   code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal
>   to the value of:
>
> ```
> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The first call to `hashCode()` is executed when adding an `Employee` to your `set` variable, as it's needed in order to calculate which bucket to put it in.

The second call is a bit sneaker. Any `Collection`'s default `toString()` is a coma-delimited concatination of all its elements `toString()`s enclosed by square brackets (e.g., `[object1, object2]`). Any object's default `toString()`, if you don't override it is `getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())`. Here, since you don't override `Employee`'s `toString()`, it's called again when you print `set`.