# How does a hashSet admit elements

Tags: java, equals, hashcode, hashset

I have a list of objects that I need to add to a HashSet, say `List<Node> books`. Say further that no two books are equal in the very sense that their `equals` method would each return false; say, however, that their `hashCode` method each return `1`. I am using this extreme case so that I can understand fully how admission works. So my question is this: Will the HashSet admit all my objects?

```
public class Book{
  ...
  @Override
  public boolean equals(Book other){
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode(){
    return 1;
  }
}
```

recall that hashSet does not admit duplicates.

I am wondering about this because by the very name a hashSet uses a hash of the object. Is that hash by any chance related to the hashCode of the object being added?

And yes I am [aware of](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#add(E))

> Adds the specified element to this set if it is not already present.
>   More formally, adds the specified element e to this set if this set
>   contains no element e2 such that (e==null ? e2==null : e.equals(e2)).
>   If this set already contains the element, the call leaves the set
>   unchanged and returns false.

But how are the hashCode of the object related to its hash value in the HashSet?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hashcode and Equals for Hashset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396939/hashcode-and-equals-for-hashset)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `Set` is composed of *buckets* to speed up searching.
When new object is added to a `Set`, its *hash* is evaluated using object's `hashCode()` method.

Then, based on that *hash*, the `Set` decides which bucket the object is to be stored in.

Then, when you search for an object inside that `Set` (using for example `contains()` method), the hash is evaluated again, and then the `Set` iterates over all the elements in a single bucket (instead of iterating over all elements of a `Set`). This makes it much faster, because - usually - set elements are distributed (more or less) equally among many buckets.

In your case, all the objects will be stored in a single bucket, thus your `Set` will not really work differently (performance-wise, that is) than a `List`.

And answering the original question: Yes, it will store all your objects as long, as their `equals()` is implemented correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Use this answer:
[How does a Java HashMap handle different objects with the same hash code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493605/how-does-a-hashmap-work-in-java)
and the information, that `HashSet<E>` is just a `HashMap<E, Object>`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm slightly confused by your question.  The HashSet will use the `hashCode()` method of the element you add (the `List<Node> books` in this case).  So if you add the `List` itself, HashSet will call hashCode on the `List`, not on `Book`, unless you add the `Book` elements individually.  If you add them individually, it was call the `hashCode()` you defined in your question.

As a side note, don't ever return a constant value in your `hashCode()`.  See [Best implementation for hashCode method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113511/hash-code-implementation)