# Duplicates Objects, java List

Tags: java, list, hashset

i have the following code, it helps me to delete duplicates elements from the List:

```
 public static void main(String[] argv)
{

// Créer un objet ArrayList
List<String> array_L = new ArrayList();

// Ajout des éléments avec doublon
array_L.add("Londre");
array_L.add("Paris");
array_L.add("New York");
array_L.add("Londre");
array_L.add("Paris");
array_L.add("Londre");

System.out.println ("Contenu avec doublon: "+array_L);

// Créer une liste de contenu unique basée sur les éléments de ArrayList
Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<String>(array_L);

// Créer une Nouvelle ArrayList à partir de Set
List<String> array_L2 = new ArrayList<String>(mySet);

// Afficher le contenu de ArrayList
System.out.println("Contenu sans doublon: "+mySet);
  }
```

then im trying to move a little forward, and to create a List of objects(Book for example):

```
    public static void main(String[] argv)
{

// Créer un objet ArrayList
List<Book> array_L = new ArrayList<Book>();

// Ajout des éléments avec doublon
Book b=new Book();
b.setName("Londre");
b.setSbn(123);

Book b2=new Book();
b2.setName("Paris");
b2.setSbn(1);

Book b3=new Book();
b3.setName("Londre");
b3.setSbn(123);
array_L.add(b);
array_L.add(b2);
array_L.add(b3);

System.out.println ("Contenu avec doublon: "+array_L);

// Créer une liste de contenu unique basée sur les éléments de ArrayList
Set<Book> mySet = new HashSet<Book>(array_L);



// Afficher le contenu de ArrayList
System.out.println("Contenu sans doublon: "+mySet);
 }
```

the Book Object

```
public class Book {
String name;
 int sbn;

  //getters and setters
}
```

so at the end it's keeps all the data, including the duplicates one

Comment: You need to override hashCode() and equals() methods into class Book. for making it unique(reduce duplicate).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396939/hashcode-and-equals-for-hashset

Comment: I think you should override `equals` method. So `List` can detect it is duplicated

Comment: thank you so much, it's under control now

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `Set` to eliminate duplicates from a List. So far, so good.

The problem is that the constructor of `HashSet` has no way to find out if 2 `Book`s are the same.

Let your IDE generate the methods `equals` and `hashCode` in the class `Book` to fix this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

> In your case, you are adding different objects(which are not located
>   on same memory location because of create using 'new' keyword.)

so, far it becomes unique then each other, to fix it.

You need to decorate your Book Class into following manner,

```
class Book {
    private String name;
    private int sbn;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getSbn() {
        return sbn;
    }

    public void setSbn(int sbn) {
        this.sbn = sbn;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.getSbn();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        Book b1 = (Book) obj;
        if (b1.getName().equals(this.getName())) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```